# ContentType change failed on SystemUpdate

Tags: content-type

I set my library default ContentType as "A", then i want to change it by some rule
if i use SystemUpdate() it can not change ContentType to B

```
  if (type== "A") {
      item["ContentTypeId"] = list.ContentTypes["A"].Id;
  } else if (type== "B") {
      item["ContentTypeId"] = list.ContentTypes["B"].Id;
  }
  ......
  item["something"]="text";
  ......
  item.SystemUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the content type name as well:

```
if (type == "A") {
    item["ContentTypeId"] = list.ContentTypes["A"].Id;
    item["Content Type"] = list.ContentTypes["A"].Name;
} else if (type == "B") {
    item["ContentTypeId"] = list.ContentTypes["B"].Id;
    item["Content Type"] = list.ContentTypes["B"].Name;
}
.......
item.SystemUpdate();
```

But, actually, looking at your code, if you have a variable called "`type`" that is an identifier of the content type you want to use, you don't even need the `if..then..else` statement:

```
........
// code in here that sets the value of "type"
// to be either "A" or "B"
........
item["ContentTypeId"] = list.ContentTypes[type].Id;
item["Content Type"] = list.ContentTypes[type].Name;
........
item.SystemUpdate();
```

That would set the content type based on the value of `type`, whether it's "A" or "B".

Comment: I found if i change ContentTypeId only then call item.SystemUpdate(), the item will change ContentType, if i do more things like change properties (like: item["XmlType"]="Old") then call item.SystemUpdate(), the ContentType will restore to default ContentType. At last i change the ContentType and call Update again after change all properties and call Update(), this could works.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is changing the other properties that is causing the content type change to fail.  I have successfully changed content types by changing the ContentTypeId and Content Type (name) properties only, and then immediately calling SystemUpdate(), before trying to set any other properties.  So yes, maybe trying to change the content type only, calling an update, and then proceeding to change other properties, will work.